# How do you append how long it takes to add up a sequence of numbers to a file in Bash?

Tags: bash, time, append

I am trying to time how long it takes to add a sequence of even numbers and append the result to a file.
I have the following code:

```
time sequence 12 2 684 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' >> NewFile
```

I get the total number from the addition but not the time it takes to do the addition. The time is working as I get:

```
real 0m0.002s
user 0m0.000s
sys  0m0.000s
```

I have tried to use brackets and curly braces:

```
(time ls)
```

and

```
{time ls; }
```

But it still does not append.

Comment: `not the time it takes to do the addition` you are "getting it", but it's not saved into the `NewFile`. What do you want to happen?

Comment: to time how long it takes to perform the calculation and insert it into the file called NewFile

Comment: See: [9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time` is a shell keyword. `time` prints to standard error.

You could redirect standard error to standard output of your whole command and redirect standard output to `newFile`. This will redirect the output of `awk` and `sequence` that get's to standard output to the file too. Also note that this measures the time of the whole pipeline, not only `seq` command.

```
{ time seq 10 | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' ;} >> NewFile 2>&1
```

Comment: I still only get the total from the calculation inserted in the file and not how long the calculation took to execute. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that is of relevance

Comment: Thanks very much To clarify, can you recommend any resources about why the 2>&1 is of relevance please? And the extra curly brackets also please?

Comment: bash manual https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections and bashfaq is a good resource on certain topics https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 maybe https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/017